# WCF: The user specified maximum retry count for a particular message has been exceeded

Tags: wcf

Getting this WCF error, and no idea how to fix it:

System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: The sequence has been terminated by the remote endpoint. The user specified maximum retry count for a particular message has been exceeded. Because of this the reliable session cannot continue. The reliable session was faulted.

Any ideas welcome :(

Answer (score 1):

From the error message, it would appear that you're using reliable messaging. One of its features is that if a message transfer fails, it will be retried - up to a maximum number of attempts.

Obviously, in your setup, this max number has been maxed out. This might indicate a problem with the network, or your service code, or both. Really hard to tell from here without knowing what you're doing and what your setup is......

I guess the main question would be: do you really need the reliable messaging feature? What are you trying to achieve with this? If you could turn it off, you wouldn't be seeing those errors... can you switch to some other mechanism, maybe message queueing (MSMQ)? Or can you rearchitect your app so you can live with the odd chance that one message might get delivered "out of band" ?