# The maximum retry count has been exceeded with no response from the remote endpoint

Tags: wcf

I am calling a method in my WCF service that performs time-consuming data operations.  I also require reliable sessions.

When I call this method with reliable sessions enabled I get the following error after about 4 minutes:

> The maximum retry count has been
>   exceeded with no response from the
>   remote endpoint. The reliable session
>   was faulted. This is often an
>   indication that the remote endpoint is
>   no longer available.

I realize this question has been [asked alot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2394084/wcf-the-user-specified-maximum-retry-count-for-a-particular-message-has-been-exc), but every answer I have seen suggests that something is going wrong in the backend and/or that reliable messaging should be disabled.

In my case, I can disable reliable messaging and it completes in about 4 minutes without any errors.  In fact, I can see all of the DB calls in Profiler - it appears to be finishing in both cases, only I get an error when reliable messaging is enabled.  I can't find any errors in the trace log that don't reference reliable sessions.

Any ideas on why I get an error with reliable session enabled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What type of binding are you using?

In your configuration, do you have a reliabilitySession inactivityTimeout value set?

Something like:

```
<binding name = "MyBinding">
  <reliabilitySession inactivityTimeout = "00:24:00" />
</binding>
```

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.reliablesession.inactivitytimeout.aspx) or chapter one of Juval Lowy's Programming WCF Services ([link](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596805494/)).

What else do you have configured in your binding?

Comment: I bumped up everything to ridiculous values and still never completed the call successfully.  From what I could tell, the lists I was populating were getting so large that even simple operations could not compute due to a lack of memory.  Maybe enabling reliable sessions pushed it over the edge?  I went to a paging mechanism (i.e. process data in batches) and the routine finishes fine now with reliable session enabled and normal timeout values.

Comment: Excellent that you found a solution!  :)  Iterative development for the win!